# Tensorflow: how to keep batch dimension when using tf.where()?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to select elements differents from zero and work with them later. My input tensor has batch dimension, so I want to keep it and don't mix data over batches. I think `tf.gather_nd()` would work for me, but first I have to get the indexes of the desired data and I found `tf.where()`. I have tried the following:

```py
img = tf.constant([[[1., 0., 0.], 
                    [0., 0., 2.],
                    [0., 3, 0.]], 
                   [[1., 2., 3.], 
                    [0., 0., 1.], 
                    [0., 0., 0.]]], dtype='float32') # shape [2, 3, 3]

indexes = tf.where(tf.not_equal(img, 0.))
```

I would expect `indexes` to keep batch dimension, however it has shape `[7, 2]`. I suspect the problem comes from having different number of points that satisfies the condition in different batches.

Is there a way to get the indexes keeping batch dimension? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** `indexes` has shape `[7, 3]` where first dim refers to number of points and the second dim refers to the position of the point (incluiding which batch it belongs to). But I need `indexes` to have the specific batch dimension, because later I want to use it to ghater data from `img`:

```py
Y = tf.gather_nd(img, indexes)
```

I want `Y` to have batch dimension, but as `indexes` hasn't, I get a flat tensor with data from different bateches mixed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you may have done something wrong : when I run your code, `indexes` is of dimension `(7,3)` and not `(7,2)`. The `3` correspond to your 3 dimensions, whereas the `7` corresponds to the number of non-zero elements in `img`.

Full result of `sess.run(indexes)` :

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
      [0, 1, 2],
      [0, 2, 1],
      [1, 0, 0],
      [1, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 2],
      [1, 1, 2]])
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry for that. But even with that, data from all batches are mixed, although I have information about corresponding batch. What I want is `indexes` to have a separate batch dimension: `[2, X, 3]`. That's because I'm using `indexes` later with `Y = gather_nd(img, indexes)`, and need `Y`to have batch dimension.

Comment: As you mentionned in the question, it's not possible since all samples in the batch do not have the same amount of non-zero elements. You may, however, want to perform some post-processing of the output of `tf.where` in order to have the format that you want

Answer (score 0):

You may use `tf.math.top_k()` to get values and indices with batch from inputs based on their values and then compute and apply mask to the values and indices.

```
img = tf.constant([[[1., 0., 0.], 
                    [0., 0., 2.],
                    [0., 3, 0.]], 
                   [[1., 2., 3.], 
                    [0., 0., 1.], 
                    [0., 0., 0.]]], dtype='float32') # shape [2, 3, 3]

values, indices = tf.math.top_k(img, k=3)
# values would be 
# [[[1., 0., 0.], [2., 0., 0.], [3., 0., 0.]],
#  [[3., 2., 1.], [1., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 0.]]]
# indices would be
# [[[0, 1, 2], [2, 0, 1], [1, 0, 2]],
#  [[2, 1, 0], [2, 0, 1], [0, 1, 2]]]

mask = tf.cast(values, dtype=tf.bool)
# mask would be
# [[[True, False, False], [True, False, False], [True, False, False]],
#  [[True, True, True], [True, False, False], [False, False, False]]]
```

Now you can get non-zero values of `img` by using `values` and `mask` and also get non-zero indices of `img` by using `indices` and `mask`. And you can use `tf.gather()` to get values from `img` and `indices` as like:

```
values2 = tf.gather(img, indices, batch_dims=2)
# values2 will be same with the above values
```